# There is a secret message in the picture

Tags: cipher, visual, steganography, mystery

There is a secret message in the picture, can you find it?

[image: Muko and the Secret]

This picture is from the 50 trillion dollars challenge from the free ebook "Muko and the Secret". This one is already solved so I hope I do not violate any rules here.

Best regards,
Greg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could the solution be

> **IMAGE**? The [second puzzle that was posted from this book](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75934/) was solved using some morse code cleverly incorporated into the art. Assuming that this puzzle would be similar, I searched this puzzle for anything morse-code like and noticed that there are some strange lines that go across the bottom edge of the pacifier, here.[image: here]They read "*short short long long short long long long short short*". Splitting the morse code up where there is a *slightly* bigger gap, and translating to English, we get the word **IMAGE**.

Comment: +1 My only problem is this doesn't explain a lot of the image, but that's about all I see too...

Comment: @theREALyumdub yeah, I thought that too. But, same goes with the other puzzle that was posted... there's so much detail on the tiling but the solution is just "the stone's sizes" interpreted as Morse code.

Comment: I am sorry, @Hugh can you specify which part of the picture? it's hard for me to see it @,@

Comment: @QLAN https://i.imgur.com/epg8sw6r.jpg

Comment: @QLAN I've edited it into the answer.

Comment: I think this is a likely answer because if it didn't have anything to do with the answer it would look different.

Comment: @Hugh Yes, correct. A bit of explanation here. The images are from the book - their purpose is to enrich the story. The secret messages are addition and they serve different purpose. Congratulations.

Comment: @aivirai oh, that would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Could the answer be related to...

> Felix [Mendelssohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Mendelssohn)?
>  Basicely, there are Mendelbrot factals on a dummy... thus ... Mendel-son?

Comment: I will post another one that was solved and that can be treated as a clue to this one. Mandelbrot set is not connected to the secret message.