# There is a secret message in the picture #2

Tags: cipher, visual, steganography, mystery

There is a secret message in the picture, can you find it?

This solution is also a clue (how to solve) to the previous one - [There is a secret message in the picture](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75917/there-is-a-secret-message-in-the-picture/75926).

[image: Muko and the Secret - secret message]

This picture was neither used in the book nor it is a part of the 50 trillion dollars challenge so I hope it does not violate any rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the answer is:

> **MUKO**

Because

> There are rocks in the art that indicate morse code, with the square rocks being dashes and the skinny rectangle rocks being dots.
>
>   Translating from morse code,
>
> ```
> - -   = M
> . . - = U
> - . - = K
> - - - = O
> ```
>
> We get the word **MUKO**. I don't know what a "MUKO" is but that's the only answer I see. :)

Comment: The e-book mentioned in part 1 of this is called “Muko and the Secret”- perhaps this has something to do with that?

Comment: That is correct. Knowing how to solve this one the previous one will be much easier.